# Bootstrap pull-right badge in a list

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap 3.3.7 and in my sidebar I have a list from php while function.

To print a value and formatting for bootstrap use this:

```
<li><a href="page.php?home=<?php echo $home_id; ?>"><?php echo $home_desc; ?></a><span class="badge">10</span></li>
```

With this code, I have the result in below image.

[image]

I have try some solution on stackoverflow answers but not work for me. How to pull right the badge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you want to pull it to the right, but you haven't added anything. Try adding the `pull-right` class like this:

```
<li>
  <span class="badge pull-right">10</span>
  <!----------------^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
  <a href="page.php?home=<?php echo $home_id; ?>"><?php echo $home_desc; ?></a>
</li>
```

The [`pull-right`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats) class is one of the quick float helper classes, applies `float: right` to the elements and will give you the desired effect.

Comment: Almost 100k Praveen way to go

Comment: @PhiterFernandes LoL. Thanks mate... `:D`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: Thanks but in this case, the badge result not inline whit the text

Comment: @Frankie Screenshot plz. `:)` And also somewhere replicable. So that it is easy to debug. Now I guess you would have understood why I asked for a snippet?

Comment: refresh and see image :) I have post an image in the first message

Comment: @Frankie Saw it man... You need to give some `margin-top` for the badge CSS.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: how to make this?

Comment: `.badge {margin-top: 5px;}` Adjust the 5px accordingly, put the code in your CSS file.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: Thanks for your support! I have resolve this problem.